# What does -Wreinterpret-base-class mean in Clang / C++?

Tags: c++, clang

I have this class hierarchy:

```
class Base {
  // no virtual stuff
}

class Property : Base {
  // no virtual stuff
}

typedef const Property* PropertyID;

template<typename T>
class TypedProperty : public Property {

  // One virtual method
  virtual bool ValidateValue(T& value) const {  return true; }

  inline const T& GetDefaultValue() const { return m_default_value; }

}
```

Then later it's used like this:

```
template<typename T>
const T& DoSomething(PropertyID property) {
  return reinterpret_cast<const TypedProperty<T>*>(property)->GetDefaultValue();
}
```

Clang spits out this warning:

> warning: 'reinterpret_cast' to class 'const TypedProperty *' from its base at non-zero offset 'PropertyID' (aka 'const Property *') behaves differently from 'static_cast' [-Wreinterpret-base-class]

And "Fix-it" in Xcode says:

> Use 'static_cast' to adjust the pointer correctly while downcasting.

What does this mean especially the "from its base at non-zero offset" part?

What could actually go wrong using `reinterpret_cast` vs `static_cast`: it's just (correctly AFAIK) casting pointers? I know for a fact the passed object is a `const TypedProperty<T>*`.

Comment: There may have little pointer arithmetic involved in fact (think about vtable, multiple inheritance, ...)

Comment: @Jarod42: In theory, but not in this case; maybe the compiler warning is too pessimistic?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Why not use the safe way ? and OP doesn't show all code (as he try to call undeclaared `GetDefaultValue()`)

Comment: @Jarod42: Absolutely, static_cast is to be preferred here.  I didn't mean to imply that I thought the code was optimal.

Comment: @Pol: small [Demo](http://ideone.com/bncZX3) to show the difference.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect that `TypedProperty` has a virtual method. I didn't think it was relevant, but apparently it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The info in the question seems to deny the multiple inheritance answer.  So the vtable answer is more likely.

If `TypedProperty` had at least one virtual function and `Property` had no virtual functions, you would get exactly the described problem.

The first thing in a `TypedProperty` object would be the vtable pointer and the second thing would be the `Property` base class.  If you `static_cast` from a `Property*` to a `TypedProperty*` the compiler would adjust by subtracting the size of the vtable pointer.  If you `reinterpret_cast` there is no adjustment, so the resulting pointer would be incorrect.

The "non-zero offset" in the error message tells you there is some difference in the pointers.  The only question was whether it is something such as multiple inheritance (which the question seems to show is not the case) or something else.

Now the original question was updated to show the cause was that combination of having at least one virtual function in `TypedProperty` and none in `Property` nor in its base class(es).  Please understand, this failure of `reinterpret_cast` to do the job of `static_cast` is an implementation specific detail that happens to match across virtually all implementations.  **But** the standard answer is that such a `reinterpret_cast` is **always wrong!**.  You can never `reinterpret_cast` to convert a valid base class pointer to a valid derived class pointer.

If you had no virtual functions in`TypedProperty`, or you had at least one in a base class, the `reinterpret_cast` would work in place of `static_cast` but would still be wrong.  That is an example of undefined behavior working by accident.  Don't ever rely on it.

Comment: There's indeed a single virtual method in `TypedProperty` which I forgot to mention in my question. It's updated now.

Answer (score 3):

```
struct A{ int x; };
struct B:A{};
struct C:A,B{};
```

here we have 3 types.  An instance of `C` has two instances of `A` in it.

The addresses of those two instances differ.

A reinterpret cast will simply take the pointer-value of the address, and treat it as if it was a pointer to `C`.  And the instance of `C` has exactly one address, not two, so both of the sub-object `A`s cannot have that value.

Going up will also fail to work (`reinterpret_cast<B*>(pointer_to_c)`), but using explicit casts when going up is an even sillier idea than using `reinterpret_cast` when going down.

In general, `reinterpret_cast` is only a good idea on pointers if you did an opposite `reinterpret_cast` on the other side, or where you are using it for `char*` to get at raw bytes.

Comment: More to the point, I think reinterpret_cast<B*>(c) will almost certainly not point at a B, but the first A.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Yakks example, which involves a diamond, you can get it via simple multiple inheritance:

```
struct A { int x; };

struct B { int y; };

struct C : A, B {};
```

In this case, the A and B objects within C can't have the same address. One of them will, one will be offset. Basically, it's not safe to reinterpret cast from child to base in general, you should static cast.